# Из формы обратной связи через раз приходят пустые поля

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

[image: Вот что приходит]Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки ! К сожалению я не сильно разбираюсь в программировании и очень прошу, помогите.
У меня на сайте есть форма обратной связи, ajax + php, так же я добавил занесение введенных значений в SQL базу, но иногда значения приходят пустыми, хотя все поля required, в SQL базе так же иногда появляются пустые записи. Не могу локализовать проблему, сколько раз не пытался отправлять письма - все ок.

Вот мой код

```
<form action="javascript:void(null);" id="form" class="form" name="FORM">
 <input type="text" name="contact" required="required" id="input1" class="input" placeholder="E-mail или телефон" maxlength="30">
 <textarea type="text" name="question" required="required" id="input2" class="input" placeholder="Напишите Ваш вопрос" maxlength="300"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отправить">
</form>



$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form").submit(function () { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //Метод отправки
                url: "php/mail.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
                data: form_data,
                success: function () {
                    //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                    alert("Спасибо! Ответим, как только сможем :)");
                    show('none');
                },
                error: function (xhr, str) {
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseCode);

                }
            });
        });
    });





<?
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]require 'c.php';
var_dump($_POST);
{ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля 
        $to = 'example@mail.ru'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>'.$_POST['contact'].'</p>
                        <p>'.$_POST['question'].'</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: <contact@example.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
};
//соединение с базой
$result = "INSERT INTO clients (mail) values('$contact')";
mysql_query($result);
mysql_close($mysql);
?>
```

Приложу два примера, что ИНОГДА приходит на почту и заносится в SQL базу. Затер адреса от недоброжелателей :)

Comment: А где код с этой строчки: `Проверка отправилось ли наше поля`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Я удалил его, т.к. не был уверен в его правильности :(

Comment: Проблема локализовалась, не приходят данные с айфонов !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что Safari не понимает required и некоторые невнимательные пользователи тупо жмут "Отправить", сделал так 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser

Comment: при данном решение все равно можно обойти валидацию и вы опять получите тотже результат т.к проверка только на стороне клиента...

Comment: Смысл не в том, что кто-то обходил валидацию, а в том, что пользователи по незнанию могли нажимать кнопку "заказать", вводя администрацию сайта в заблуждение, которая получала пустые заявки. Скребет в самых неприличных местах, когда теряешь клиентов из-за таких вещей :)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно валидировать данные либо на стороне сервеа или либо на стороне лкиента а вообщето лучше и там и там,

на сервере нада делать валидацию потому что:

- весь ваш код на стороне клиента - клиент просто может отключать или менять на свой любой код по своему желанию.

на клиенте нада делать валидацию потому что:

- нет смысла отправлять данные на сервер и проводить там валидацию, если можно не грузя cервер провалидировать это на клиенте. (не всеже будут игнорировать вашу валидацию на клиенте)

на стороне клиента для валидации:

это

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
```

заменить на

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
if ($("#input1").val() && $("#input2").val()) {
```

ну и соответсвенно добавить  закрывающую скобку там где это нужно }

на стороне сервера в самом начале файла:

```
if (($_POST['contact'] == '') || ($_POST['question'] == '')) {
//редирект назад с сообщением о ошибке валидации например так
echo "<script>document.location='index.php?error=1';</script>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а валидация подразумевает защиту от SQL-инъекции ? В вашем примере мы просто проверяем, не пусты ли значения, так ?

Comment: да речь же шла только о валидации на заполненность.

Comment: Ага, сделано, только мне до сих пор не понятно, почему все-таки приходили пустые значения...

Comment: вариаций много может быть...бразуеров в мире знаете сколько?....не только основные хром файрфокс ИЕ...но есть много диковинных....они просто могут не знать тега required

Comment: В том то и печаль, что require не при чем. С другой такой же формы иногда приходят выбранные чекбоксы, но без контактных данных, скоро ковролин начну жрать от непонимания

Comment: Проблема локализовалась, не приходят данные с айфонов !

Comment: ну вот айфоны не знают атрибута require...у проблемы одинаковое решение не завиимо от источника проблемы....